# Can't open xlsm file from SSIS package job

Tags: vb.net, excel, ssis, excel-interop

I have a number of SSIS jobs that open some Excel files and manipulate them. The task within the job that opens the Excel file is basically the same in each job, it just points to a different Excel file. Each of these jobs work fine except for one. But even this one works when ran manually from the package and not in the job.

The applicable code is:

```
Dim reportLocation As String
Dim oXL As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

reportLocation = "\\testlocation\share\test.xlsm"

'Open Excel instance
oXL = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
oXL.Visible = False

'Open the Excel file to edit
oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(reportLocation) 'Error here
```

The error received is as below:

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '\\testlocation\share\test.xlsm'.
>   There are several possible
>   reasons:
>
> • The file name or path does not exist. • The file is being used by
>   another program. • The workbook you are trying to save has the same
>   name as a currently open workbook.    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object
>   UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object
>   WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin,
>   Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter,
>   Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)    at
>   ScriptTask_ffa2c543b1224c3987d5764694df1079.ScriptMain.Main()

This was the latest package to be created, and was a copy/paste job, just changing the locations it looks for the files. I have checked all permissions and there is no issue there. I've even given access to "Everyone" to see if that was an issue, but the same error occurred. The file definitely exists in the location and it is not open by anyone. What possible reason is there that this specific file can't be opened when run in a SQL job but can be opened when run manually in the package? I have also tried changing the job to run the package as a user with full admin access via a proxy. But still no joy.

Comment: Are the other files .xlsm, not .xlsx?  I can only suppose that the server's default macro-handling setting is different than the local machine's.

Comment: All the other files are .xlsm and all are accessed via the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having revisited some answers on here for similar questions I was able to find the solution. This can be seen at [Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Timesheet\App_Data\Template.xlsx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106381/microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-c-inetpub-wwwroot-timesheet-app)

I created the directory `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop` on the server and it miraculously now works. I had looked at this yesterday and thought the directory already existed so didn't implement this solution. But having a second look at it today shows the directory didn't exist and creating it fixed it.

Now the question is, why does this work?! But that is possibly another question.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a valid path to me:

`\\testlocation\test.xlsm`

You at least need a share name after the host name:

`\\testlocation\Share\test.xlsm`

How do the paths look for your working files? I'm guessing they have a share.

Comment: I replaced the actual full unc path with that above for showing on here. The path is correct in the application, all files are held in the same location. This is not the issue.