# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I working on the Excel in the server and when I trying to open my Excel file with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, I have this error:

> Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC

I check my access to my file, and my IIS account have a full control on this. This is my code :

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(
                              Filepath,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing,
                              true
                          );
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception HResult 0x800a03ec when trying to open Excel with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078729/exception-hresult-0x800a03ec-when-trying-to-open-excel-with-microsoft-office-int)

Comment: This seems to be a fairly generic error, there are quite a few posts on this and other sites referencing it - you may want to check if the following link is relevant for what you are doing as well; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0

Comment: It is a pretty generic Excel runtime error.  Find hits by googling "excel workbook open error 1004".  Lotsa hits.