# Server can download excelpackage file but client can't

Tags: c#, asp.net, excelpackage

I was trying to create **excelpackage download function**.
When i try it on my server or on my local development server, the download button works and it sends Excel file to the browser. But after i deployed and try to download from client, it returns nothing.

**Result using Chrome**

[image: Result using Chrome]

**Result using Firefox**

[image]

Here is my code :

```
if (Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + departmentName + ".xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
    }
```

I tried to follow the instructions that were provided here,

[Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Timesheet\App_Data\Template.xlsx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106381/microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-c-inetpub-wwwroot-timesheet-app)

But still won't fix my problem.

Comment: where are the codes where you get your files? with your path, so on

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with my file generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Response.IsClientConnected)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + departmentName + ".xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Somehow when i change

```
Response.Close()
```

to

```
Response.End()
```

It works.