# Change excel sheet names with RDLC

Tags: c#, excel, rdlc

I'm trying to create a report with RDLC and I can't change the sheet names in excel. When i'm trying to change it from RDLC properties (by grouping) i have an error of invalid RDLC file (I read over the internet and discovered that this option doesn't work with RDLC). If I save the file (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/...) and then I try to open it with Interop.Excel it crashes on opening ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106381/microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-c-inetpub-wwwroot-timesheet-app)).

I don't want to create any other folders or give permissions to other folders. What other options I have?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to change the name in Excel worksheet - assign PageName property of the table (Tablix) in the report.

Here is more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets/

Comment: Not working for me. The internet say that this solution doesn't work with RDLC.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I use rdlc too and it works fine. There are some limitations though. What do you use as an expression?

Comment: I have a error like: Error 1 The tablix 'Tablix1' has an invalid TablixMember. All TablixMember elements in a TablixColumnHierarchy must have the RepeatOnNewPage property set to false. I am grouping the records by one field, split the groups to different sheets. I tried to rename the sheets for every group. Searched over the internet, none of the fixes worked for me.