# Error when try read data from Excel File in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost

In an ASP.NET MVC app, I am trying to read data from Excel file but I get this error:

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\qqq\Content\Uploads\dataFile.xls'.
>
> There are several possible reasons:
>
> • The file name or path does not exist.
> • The file is being used by another program.
> • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

The error appears in production mode, but in development mode there's no problem.

I am making host on Local Host on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple example and reproduced your problem. Please check if the following directories exist:

For a 32-bit version of Office on a 32-bit Windows computer or a 64-bit version of Office on a 64-bit Windows computer:

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop`

For the 32-bit version of Excel/Office on a 64-bit Windows computer:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`

In most cases (my test too), you should be able to solve this problem by creating the first directory, unless your environment is somewhat special, you can try creating a second directory to see if it works for you. For more details, you could refer to this similar case: [Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Timesheet\App_Data\Template.xlsx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106381/microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-c-inetpub-wwwroot-timesheet-app)

Comment: Yes I created the first folder and it worked with me, Thank you

Comment: Glad your issue is resolved. I found the same post in the Q&A forum, was it also posted by you?

Comment: Yes, I accepted your there too, Thanks